# proving a formula related with ζ

Tags: complex-analysis, zeta-functions

Could someone show me how to prove the following formula?

prove that
when $a_n=\frac{ζ(2n)}{Π^{2n}}$  (n=1.2.3……)

$$(n+\frac{1}{2})a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{n-k}{a_k}$$ (n≥2)  and find out the value of $a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6$

zeta-function is soooo difficult and i almost give up

I need your help and thank you very much

Comment: Same answer as in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941150/proving-equation-including-the-zeta-function), this time differentiate both sides to make $\sum_n  (2n-2) a_n z^{2n-3}$ appear.

Comment: Your $a_n$ is nothing but $ (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} B_{2n}$ where $B_n$ are Bernoulli's number.

Comment: I finally get to know what you mean and it's really helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The generating function for $\zeta(2n)/\pi^{2n}$ is

$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi x}{2}\cot(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}x^{2n}.$$

Combining this with the fact that $\cot(x)$ satisfies the differential equation

$$f’(x)=-1-(f(x))^2$$

and using the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) gives the desired  recurrence relation.